# Is node passport custom callback as middleware possible for express routes?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, jwt

I'm creating a simple Rest Api with node.js and I'm securing it with jwt tokens, I have set up passport and passport-jwt to authenticate which works fine and if there is an error with the jwt token or its non existent, passport will send a 401 and body text of 'Unauthorized'. I know how to change the error for a route to send back a custom error message which I want by doing the following;

```
router.route('/test')
    .put(function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.send("Custom Unauthorised").end();  }
        return res.send("Test Route Accessed").end();
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

I have around 20 routes and I name them similar to the following;

```
router.route('/books/:id/authors').get(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), myRoutes.books.authors);
```

Now you will notice that I store resource specific routes in their own files (i.e  myRoutes.books) so my question is, is there a way to have the custom callbacks as middleware that wont require a major restructure of the route files?

Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly your question.

Create a function let's call it jwt

```
function jwt (req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, function(err, user, info) { 
        if (err) { return next(err); } 
        if (!user) { return res.send("Custom Unauthorised").end(); } 
        // edit as per comment
        //return res.send("Test Route Accessed").end();
        req.user = user;   // Forward user information to the next middleware
        next();
    })(req, res, next);
}
```

And use it as middleware

```
router.get('/bla', jwt, handleBla);
```

Comment: Sweet, that works as I need, just a noob is all, btw in the jwt function you need to remove the return and replace with a next() call and it goes onto the route :) cheers

Comment: There is a problem with the req.user that passport populates, being passed to the route 'handleBla' after 'jwt'  being undefined whereas if you just use passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }) it does get passed along, any ideas?

Comment: What problem is there? Is the user not populated?

Comment: It's populated in the above function but the next middleware (the route) it is undefined.

Comment: Just before calling next() does req.user exist?

Comment: If not simply add it like req.user = user; just above next()

Comment: I thought it would had simply been passed on as its available the standard way, your solution works fine, cheers

Comment: is this the same for `'token'` when using `'passport-accesstoken'`